# Lighting an LED through Pi 4 Model B using Assembly

Tags: gpio, assembly

I have been struggling to light an LED using my raspberry pi 4 model b but have not been able to find a solution.

My assembly code :

```
.section .init
.globl _start
_start:

mov r0, #0xF0000000
orr r0, #0x0E000000
orr r0, #0x00200000
orr r0, #0x00000004
mov r1, #1
lsl r1, #18
str r1, [r0]

mov r0, #0xF0000000
orr r0, #0x0E000000
orr r0, #0x00200000
orr r0, #0x0000001C
mov r1, #1
lsl r1, #16
str r1, [r0]

loop$:
b loop$
```

I am trying to light up the LED through GPIO 16. A post on the raspberry pi forums suggests that the peripheral memory base has changed to 0xFE000000 instead of 0x20000000 + the GPIO offset; neither of those memory addresses worked to light the LED.

I also installed NOOBS on a different SD card and wrote a python script to light the LED and that worked.

To learn about the bare metals of raspberry pi, I have been reading the Baking Pi tutorial by the University of Cambridge.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I skimmed Baking Pi's first two lessons and found this tutorial  very good for newbies.  I would rate it top 1% of the 100+ online tutorials I have read all these years.  Lesson 1 actually shows every step to turn on GPIO 16 LED.  Is there a step you could not follow or got stuck?

Comment: I skimmed the Troubleshooint section and read the following: Troubleshooting:
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/troubleshooting.html

"This course has not yet been updated to work with the Raspberry Pi models B+ and A+. Some elements may not work, in particular the first few lessons about the LED. It has also not been updated for Raspberry Pi v2" ...  In other words, the tutorials is perhaps 5 years out of date!

Comment: So you know how to use python to turn on a LED. But why now diving deep down to ARM assembly/machine language?

Comment: Question - I used apt-get to install the toolchain, but got errors "unable to find some archives, ..." Did you get the same error?

Comment: Hi @Rahul Wadhwani, I am catching up.  I just finished reading Lesson1 and so can more or less understand your turn-on-LED program.  I will try to copy a similar demo code from Lesson 1 and hopefully assembled it and run it.

Comment: I hope you are able to run it. Do you also have a raspberry pi 4 model b?

Comment: Hi @ Rahul Wadhwani, Yes I am using Rpi4B 2GB.  I have very little experience in "Make".  So I need to google/wiki quite a bit.  Now I got stuck when running the makefile, with the error "... missing separator, Stop" as described at the top of my updated answer.  Do you happen to know how what could be wrong?

Comment: PS - The complete listing of the makefile is in Appendix C of my answer.

Comment: I found an update of Baking Pi for Rpi2/3.  I need to see what is the difference bdetween 1 and 2/3, and if there is any hope for 4. https://github.com/mauri870/baking-pi/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @goldilocks: Thank you for your advice. My apologies for any trouble caused.  I have never heard of the StackEdit markdown editor.  I will try to see if it helps to make my answers more friendly to visitors.

"...  please don't use posted answers as scratchpads. You can continue to edit ..,  SE use a markdown editor and post them once they are ready..  StackEdit was pretty much made for that purpose, you may need a dropbox or google cloud account"